# How to get multi page JMeter Webdriver timing

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I've been using JMeter for quite a while but webdriver is new to me.
I'm trying to do some timings for a multi-page scenario and have a question.
I'm using JMeter webdriver sampler and HTMLunit:

Here is the scenario
1. Go to a web page `http://162.243.100.234`
2. Enter the word hello in the search box
3. Click on submit

What I want to get is:
1. How long it took to load the first page
2. How long it took from when I clicked on submit to when the results page was loaded

I have the following code which only gives me ONE sample timing.
How do I change it so I'll have two?

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://162.243.100.234/')

var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('s'))
searchField.click()
searchField.sendKeys(['hello'])

var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('searchsubmit'))
button.click()
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

I tried adding another sampleStart and sampleEnd but got and error.
Do I need to use two samplers somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you need to split your code into 2 pieces:

First Sampler:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://162.243.100.234')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Second Sampler:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
var searchField = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('s'))
searchField.click()
searchField.sendKeys(['hello'])
var button = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('searchsubmit'))
button.click()
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Mention `WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()` and `WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()` methods invocation

As per Using Selenium with [JMeter's WebDriver Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) guide

> WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart() and WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
>   captures sampler’s time and will track it. You can remove them, the
>   script will still work but you can’t get load time

Hope this helps

Comment: So the second sampler will be acting on the page that was the result of the request from the first sampler?

Comment: Answering my own comment. Each sampler will pickup where the last one ended making multi page scripts very easy.